# C++ Delete keyword causes `Unknown Signal`

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and to get a better understanding of how memory worked, I tried to build a dynamically sized array in c++. I successfully managed to implement the push and get functionalities, but when I tried adding the pop functionality, I stumbled upon a very weird error, for which I didn't find any similar record on the internet, that occured when using the `delete` keyword to free memory.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;


template <class T>
class Array {
    T* ptr;
    public:
        int size;

        Array(unsigned int original_size) : size(original_size) {
            ptr = (T*) malloc(size * sizeof(T));
        }
        Array () {
            size = 0;
            ptr = 0;
        }

        void set(int pos, T val) {
            ptr[pos] = val;
        }

        T get(int pos) {
            return ptr[pos];
        }

        T operator[] (int i) {
            return get(i);
        }

        void operator() (int pos, T val) {
            set(pos, val);
        }

        void add(T value) {
            ptr = (T*) realloc(ptr, (++size) * sizeof(T));
            set(size - 1, value);
        }

        T pop() {
            T temp = get(--size);

            delete (ptr + size);

            return temp;
        }
};


int main() {

    Array<int> arr(3);
    arr(0, 1);
    arr(1, 2);
    arr(2, 3);

    arr.add(4);
    arr.add(5);
    cout << arr.pop();
    cout << arr.pop();
}
```

This code fails after the invokation of the delete command in the pop method with the message `Unknown Signal`.
Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: `malloc` and `delete` do *not* go hand in hand. And you can't `delete` part of an array, only reallocate the whole array.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code, the first being the usage of `malloc` and `realloc`.  `Array<std::string> s;` -- That will not work out too well, even if you fix the issue for `Array<int>`.

Comment: As an idea, why not use the size and capacity concept used by `std::vector`? So an array have a specific size (number of elements currently in the array) and a specific capacity (the allocated space).

Comment: And you *really* need to look up [the rules of three/five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: *I stumbled upon a very weird error* -- That error is not very weird.  It is an error to  be totally expected, given the way the code is written.

Comment: `int main() { Array<int> i1;  Array<int> i2 = i1; }` -- This will also fail, even if you fix the `malloc` and `delete` issue that is currently broken.  So implementing your own dynamic array isn't as straightforward as you believed -- don't fret it, because you're not the first to try this and ran into problems.

Comment: then how is the reallocation supposed to be done?

Comment: @anom907zat *then how is the reallocation supposed to be done?* -- The "long" way.  Allocate, move data to new location, assign pointer to new location, delete old location.

Comment: and what is the difference with realloc?

Comment: @anom907zat The `malloc` and `realloc` are C functions that know nothing about C++ objects.  They do not call the constructors of non-trivially-copyable objects, such as `std::string`.  That's why an `Array<std::string>` is doomed to fail.  In C++, you use `new[]` and `delete[]`.

Comment: `T operator[] (int i)` -- And as aside, you have this issue, where `operator[]` should return a reference, and have two overloads, `const` and `non-const` similar to [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).  Your current version means that you cannot use an `Array<T>` in a `const` situation, for example  `void foo(const Array<int>& x) { int val = x[0]; }` will give a compiler error telling you that you are calling a non-const function on a const object.

Comment: "Unknown signal" exceptions are one of the (many) possible outcomes of undefined behaviour.   Using `delete` on ANY pointer that isn't EXACTLY the result of a corresponding `new` expression gives undefined behaviour.   A pointer produced by `malloc()` or `realloc()` is not the result of ANY `new` expression.

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Technically you can make C++ objects to work with `malloc()` and `free()` (though it is not trivial), but I do not see a way `realloc()` can be properly used with non-trivial C++ objects, so no, you cannot do that. Use `new[]` `delete[]` as an exercise, but use proper standard container like `std::array` or `std::vector` etc in practice.

Comment: The program doesn't throw an exception, it crashes.

Comment: Technically Program crashes with a signal SIGABRT on Linux systems, not exception. But Code posted is reproducible and question is a valid one, IDK why downvoting?

Comment: In the same vein, could memcpy be used or shall I implement the copying alogrithme myself?

Comment: Because there is no such thing as '"'Unknown signal' exception", for a start.

Comment: _Because there is no such thing as '"'Unknown signal' exception", for a start._
That's only quibbling and is in my opinion irrelevant

Comment: To be honest, I am not so versed in C++ like C, so I am not sure if you can use memcpy on ALL C++ objects and what is behavior  when objects have virtual functions or pointers. So you can, but must be careful. Because if you have pointer in object, copy will have  pointer to the same object, not a pointer to a new allocation. So both pointers. in the original and in the copy will point to the same thing. As said, you must be careful

Comment: It isn't *your* opinion that's relevant. It's the opinion of all the people who could otherwise have answered your question, but can't be bothered with deciphering imprecision or nonsense. This is a precise occupation. Be precise. It's in your own interest. You don't get to decide this.

Comment: So do you think my bad choice of words is in any way relevant to this question?

Comment: Especially because I think it didn't hinder anyone from understanding the question.

Comment: "In the same vein, could memcpy be used or shall I implement the copying alogrithme myself?" It is bad idea to use bit-for-bit copying of whole objects, but you can use memcpy() when you implement your own copy constructor or assignment operator for your class.

Comment: To sum things up, is there any way of using delete on just the pointer with an offset, or do I have to recopy the whole array minus the element I wanted to remove, and then free the whole memory block?

(This was already said at the very beginning, but what if I use `new`?)

Comment: @anom907, I reworked class with new instead of realloc() and put it in answer.

Comment: I actually got everything working, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are problematic here.

1. Using `delete` with `malloc/realloc`
2. tweaking the pointer used in `delete/free`

You allocate memory with `malloc()` for your initial `Array` and `realloc()` when you add elements to `Array` and it is OK.

and you store that memory address where `Array` allocation is made in `ptr`.

But in `pop()` method you free that allocation like this:

```
delete (ptr + size);
```

Although `delete` should be used only with `new` operator, because it will lead to undefined behavior, in this particular case compiler call `free()` instead.

So you basically tell `malloc()` to free memory but give a wrong address: pointer address + offset. This offset `size` "corrupts" the `ptr` and confuses `malloc()`.
You cannot simply free/delete just part of allocated array. I mean you can, but with `realloc()`.

`malloc` doesn't know how to handle this, so it ends with SIGABRT signal:

```
malloc_printerr (str=str@entry=0x7ffff7d32210 "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer") at ./malloc/malloc.c:5664
```

You should basically use `realloc()` in method `pop()` too, for removing elements from `Array` like this:

```
    T pop() {
        T temp = get(--size);
        ptr = (T*) realloc(ptr, (size) * sizeof(T));
        return temp;
    }
```

Or you can try reworked example where `new` operator is used:

```
template<typename T> 
class Array {
    T* ptr;
    public:
        int size;

        Array () {
            cout << "Array() Constructor" << endl;
            size = 0;
            ptr = 0;
        }

        Array(unsigned int original_size) : size(original_size) {
            cout << "Array(size) Constructor" << endl;
            ptr = new T[size];
        }

        Array(T arr[], int original_size) : size(original_size) {
            cout << "Array(arr[], size) Constructor" << endl;
            ptr = new T[size]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                ptr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        
        ~Array () {
            cout << "Array() Destructor" << endl;
            delete[] ptr;
        }

        T operator[] (int i) {
            return get(i);
        }

        void operator() (int pos, T val) {
            set(pos, val);
        }

        void set(int pos, T val) {
            ptr[pos] = val;
        }

        T get(int pos) {
            return ptr[pos];
        }

    void push(T value) {
        T* newptr = new T[++size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
            newptr[i] = ptr[i];

        newptr[size - 1] = value;
        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = newptr;
    }

    T pop() {
        T temp = get(--size);

        T* newptr = new T[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            newptr[i] = ptr[i];

        delete[] ptr;
        ptr = newptr;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

Hope it helps you learn something from this answer and comments below.

Comment: Anyway, using `delete` on memory allocated with `malloc` is undefined behaviour, even if the address was the right one.

Comment: g++ obviously takes care of that because it called free() instead.

Comment: Doesn't matter, still UB. It's more likely that their `delete` implementation uses `free`. But you shouldn't depend on that behaviour.

Comment: Compilers don't go out of their way to <expletive deleted> you until they see an advantage in doing it. And then they will <expletive deleted> you up one side and down the other to give you a faster, more efficient program.

Comment: "Although `delete` should be used with `new` operator"... Correct.  "...compiler will call free() instead."  No, that's not guaranteed.  Perhaps it does happen on your implementation.  My implementation uses separate heaps for malloc/free and new/delete and new[]/delete[].

Comment: You say:   "Although delete should be used with `new` new operator, compiler will call `free()` instead.".   Simply incorrect.    Using `delete` on a pointer returned by `malloc()` causes undefined behaviour.    Some implementations (compilers/libraries) MIGHT call `free()` in such a circumstance, but that is not required - and, worse, not all implementations do.

Comment: Mea Culpa, I forgot to explicitly state that in my case g++ would call free() instead but that calling delete in malloc() is generally UB, but reason why it failed in this case is because free() was using incorrect pointer address. I appreciate comments whcih improves or fix answer, but some people are only vindictive

Comment: That's still wrong: calling `delete` on something returned by `malloc` is not "generally" UB, it is _always_ UB, and _always_ wrong, and you should _never_ do it.

Comment: It's not vindictive for folks to (1)  point out a flat-out error in your answer  or (for anyone who has done so) to (2) down-vote because of of such an error.     The fact you consider that matching a `malloc()` with a `delete` is *generally* undefined behaviour (when it is actually undefined behaviour according to the *definition* of undefined behaviour in the standard) is a sign you have more to learn.